# Pass undefined in PHP functions and keep defaults

Tags: php

I have some code like this:

```
function mailer($email, $subject, $body, $from = '"MyApp" <noreply@myapp.com>', $replyto = '"MyApp" <noreply@myapp.com>') {
```

I want to call it, essentially, like:

```
mailer('foo@bar.com', 'FooBar', "Foo bar baz...", NULL, 'reply@to-me.com')
```

However, what happens is NULL is passed as a valid value so it tries to email NULL. What i want is to pass *nothing* for the `$from` so it uses the default but i add a custom value for the `$replyto`

In JS you could do `undefined` for the $from field and it would use the default. How do I do this in PHP?

Comment: In short - you __can't__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite it to have null as the default value and add the required default in the function instead...

```
function mailer($email, $subject, $body, 
         $from = NULL, 
         $replyto = '"MyApp" <noreply@myapp.com>') {
    if ( $from == NULL ) {
        $from = '"MyApp" <noreply@myapp.com>';
    }
```

Not as elegant as it could be.

Answer (score 2):

since there is not that undefined-functionality like in JS, you could change the Parameter orders in the method signature and put $from to last position. Another approach would be to store the defaults in the function body, which you could apply when the given parameter is null. Hope this helps.